# can I configure SSH so it does not use encryption?

Tags: ssh, tcpdump, wireshark

I have an ssh client connecting to an ssh server. I want to investigate what's going on between them, so I would like to dump the traffic with tcpdump and then analyze it with Wireshark. However, I read that I can't decrypt the traffic dump, even if I have a root access to both client and server - that's a feature of Diffie-Hallman algorithm. So I have another idea: maybe I could configure the client and the server in such a way that they don't encrypt their conversation? Or make them encrypt it with some trivial algorithm, so I can decrypt it?

Is it possible?

Comment: See [How can I disable encryption on openssh](https://serverfault.com/a/606367/267016) over on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a debugging technique I use sometimes when I can't SSH with a specific user to a server. On the server (as root), run this command:

```
/bin/sshd -p <listening port> -D -d -e
```

Now on the client that is attempting to reach the server:

```
ssh <user>@<host> -p <listening port> -vvvv
```

At this point you can go back to your server and take a look at what its displaying for stdout